# BizTalk EndpointBehavior not showing - Installing BLogical BizTalkRESTHandler

Tags: wcf, biztalk, servicebehavior

On BizTalk 2013/R2. I'm following steps here: http://blogical.se/blogs/mikael/archive/2012/05/28/rest-start-kit-for-biztalk-server.aspx.

I have GAC'ed the bLogical.BizTalk.RESTBehavior.dll, and restarted the Host Instances.

I registered the behavior in my WCFCustom Send/Receive 
When I try to create a new SendPort (solicit/response), I pick the same host instance tied to the WCFCustom adapter I setup, and on the "Behaviors" tab, I do right-click on "EndpointBehavior" and the BizTalkRESTRequetHandler does not appear.

Image below shows setup of WCF_Custom adapter for one host instance. 
[image]

Image below shows BizTalkRESTRequetHandler not showing in the list. 
[image]

Comment: Well, why are you using this?  BizTalk Server 2013 R2 supports REST oob with the WCF-WebHttp Adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  I had to close/re-open BizTalk Admin console after doing the GAC.